# DataFrame algebra in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have two dataframes

```
df1
df2
```

that I can join on `df1_keys` and `df2_keys`.

I would like to do:

1. `(A-B)`
2. `(A-B) U (B-A)`

with `A=df1` and `B=df2`.

From what I read on the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), the `how` argument for `pd.merge` supports the following options:

```
how : {‘left’, ‘right’, ‘outer’, ‘inner’}, default ‘inner’
        left: use only keys from left frame (SQL: left outer join)
        right: use only keys from right frame (SQL: right outer join)
        outer: use union of keys from both frames (SQL: full outer join)
        inner: use intersection of keys from both frames (SQL: inner join)
```

but none of them gives us directly the set operations 1 and 2 above.

For reference, below is the corresponding reference for SQL (from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-join)):

[image]

Comment: I've rolled this back to the previous version, which I think is a great question. Please ask the specific aspect separately, happy to answer it! :)

Comment: Thanks @AndyHayden I wholeheartedly agree with your edits. For anyone interested, here is a related question: [Set differences on columns between dataframes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22109361/set-differences-on-columns-between-dataframes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although these aren't supported directly, they can be achieved by tweaking with the indexes before attempting the join...

You can do set minus using the `-` operator:

```
In [11]: ind = pd.Index([1, 2, 3])

In [12]: ind2 = pd.Index([3, 4, 5])

In [13]: ind - ind2
Out[13]: Int64Index([1, 2], dtype='int64')
```

and set union with the `|` and intersection with `&`:

```
In [14]: ind | ind2
Out[14]: Int64Index([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype='int64')

In [15]: ind & ind2
Out[15]: Int64Index([3], dtype='int64')
```

So if you have some DataFrames with these indexes, you can reindex *before* you join:

```
In [21]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3), ind, ['a'])  # ind = df.index

In [22]: df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3), ind2, ['b'])  # ind2 = df2.index

In [23]: df.reindex(ind & ind2)
Out[23]:
          a
3  1.368518
```

So now you can build up whatever join you want:

```
In [24]: df.reindex(ind & ind2).join(df2.reindex(ind & ind2))  # equivalent to inner
Out[24]:
          a         b
3  1.368518 -1.335534

In [25]: df.reindex(ind - ind2).join(df2.reindex(ind - ind2))  # join on A set minus B
Out[25]:
          a   b
1  1.193652 NaN
2  0.064467 NaN
```

Comment: How would you extend this to doing the algebra on columns and not on indices? (i.e. I mean doing the set difference on a particular column, as in the diagram in the OP). I thought I could simply do  `df.set_index(columns_for_the_join)` before I join, but some of the entries in the columns are `NaN`, and when I convert this column to indices, it fails, since I can't later index my Dataframe with `ind_diff = ind - ind2` if `ind` (and therefore `ind_diff`) have NaN values.

Comment: @Josh columns are also an `Index`, so you can do the same set operations with `df.columns`. Not sure I understand what you're asking, you should be able to join on indexes with NaNs... Perhaps ask this as a new question?

Comment: Thanks @Andy I greatly appreciate your help. I have updated the OP with an example to clarify what I mean.

Comment: @Josh I think that should be a new question. The original question was a good one you shouldn't change it!