# Set differences on columns between dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

**Note:** This question is inspired by the ideas discussed in this other post: [DataFrame algebra in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22055567/dataframe-algebra-in-pandas)

Say I have two dataframes `A` and `B` and that for some column `col_name`, their values are:

```
A[col_name]   |  B[col_name]  
--------------| ------------
1             |  3
2             |  4
3             |  5
4             |  6
```

I want to compute the set difference between `A` and `B` based on `col_name`. The result of this operation should be:

The rows of `A` where `A[col_name]` didn't match any entries in `B[col_name]`.

Below is the result for the above example (showing other columns of `A` as well):

```
A[col_name] | A[other_column_1] | A[other_column_2]  
------------+-------------------|------------------ 
1           |    'foo'          |  'xyz'            ....
2           |    'bar'          |  'abc'
```

Keep in mind that some entries in `A[col_name]` and `B[col_name]` could hold the value `np.NaN`. I would like to treat those entries as **undefined BUT different**, i.e. the set difference **should return them**.

How can I do this in Pandas? (generalizing to a difference on **multiple columns** would be great as well)

Comment: When you say "undefined BUT different", do you mean keep the NaNs from A and even if NaN is/are\ also in B?

Comment: Also thanks for answering this as a separate question :)

Comment: Thanks @AndyHayden - I mean that, if we do `A-B` we should only get the NaNs in `A`, and not the NaNs in `B`. Reasoning: Anything in `B` that is undefined can be thought of as unknown to (not present in) in `A`, so it should not make it to `A-B`. Although this could depend on the actual problem and what `NaN` represent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use the Series `isin` method:

```
In [11]: df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'foo'], [2, 'bar'], [3, 'meh'], [4, 'baz']], columns = ['A', 'B'])

In [12]: df2 = pd.DataFrame([[3, 'a'], [4, 'b']], columns = ['A', 'C'])
```

Now you can check whether each item in `df1['A']` is in of `df2['A']`:

```
In [13]: df1['A'].isin(df2['A'])
Out[13]:
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
Name: A, dtype: bool

In [14]: df1[~df1['A'].isin(df2['A'])]  # not in df2['A']
Out[14]:
   A    B
0  1  foo
1  2  bar
```

I think this does what you want for NaNs too:

```
In [21]: df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'foo'], [np.nan, 'bar'], [3, 'meh'], [np.nan, 'baz']], columns = ['A', 'B'])

In [22]: df2 = pd.DataFrame([[3], [np.nan]], columns = ['A'])

In [23]: df1[~df1['A'].isin(df2['A'])]
Out[23]:
    A     B
0 1.0   foo
1 NaN   bar
3 NaN   baz
```

*Note: For large frames it may be worth making these columns an index (to perform the join as discussed in [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22055567/dataframe-algebra-in-pandas)).*

### More generally

One way to merge on two or more columns is to use a dummy column:

```
In [31]: df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'foo'], [np.nan, 'bar'], [4, 'meh'], [np.nan, 'eurgh']], columns = ['A', 'B'])

In [32]: df2 = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 'bar'], [4, 'meh']], columns = ['A', 'B'])

In [33]: cols = ['A', 'B']

In [34]: df2['dummy'] = df2[cols].isnull().any(1)  # rows with NaNs in cols will be True

In [35]: merged = df1.merge(df2[cols + ['dummy']], how='left')

In [36]: merged
Out[36]:
    A      B  dummy
0   1    foo    NaN
1 NaN    bar   True
2   4    meh  False
3 NaN  eurgh    NaN
```

The booleans were present in df2, the True has an NaN in one of the merging columns. Following your spec, we should drop those which are False:

```
In [37]: merged.loc[merged.dummy != False, df1.columns]
Out[37]:
    A      B
0   1    foo
1 NaN    bar
3 NaN  eurgh
```

*Inelegant.*

Comment: Fantastic! Since your solution depends on the use of `Series`, what would happen if we are doing the difference (i.e. join) on **multiple columns**?

Comment: Ah, that's trickier, will have to think about this. Ah wait, may be ok with DataFrame isin method (which cares about alignement).

Comment: @Josh ok, have a solution.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'isnull'`

Comment: @zhangxaochen make sure you're using an up to date version of pandas (not sure when that method was introduced), the latest stable is 0.13.1 :). Perhaps can use `pd.isnull(df2[cols]).any(1)` in older versions?

Comment: @AndyHayden yeah I've upgraded my pandas just now ;)

Comment: Thank you @AndyHayden - Sorry for the delay on this. I have provided my own answer to the question, but I am not sure it works. I will review it soon.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option that is also **not** elegant since it pre-maps the `NaN` values to some other value (`0`) so that they can be used as an index:

```
def left_difference(L, R, L_on, R_on, NULL_VALUE):
  L[L_on] = L[L_on].fillna(NULL_VALUE)
  L.set_index(L_on, inplace=True)

  R[R_on] = R[R_on].fillna(NULL_VALUE)
  R.set_index(R_on, inplace=True)

  # MultiIndex difference:
  diff = L.ix[L.index - R.index]
  diff = diff.reset_index()

  return diff
```

To make this work peroperly, `NULL_VALUE` should be a value not used by `L_on` nor `R_on`.

Comment: keep in mind this is also destructive / has side-effects: changes index of L and R and replaces NaNs with NULL_VALUE on those cols. Also diff may have different index