# Difference between df.reindex() and df.loc[]

Tags: python, pandas

Say I want to compute the [relative complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_difference#Relative_complement)  `df2 - df1` between two MultiIndex dataframes. Assuming that they have the same indexing schema, based on what I saw in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22056893/283296) from Andy Hayden, I could do the following:

```
diff_indices = df2.index - df1.index
```

And then either:

1. `df2.reindex(diff_indices, inplace=True)`

   or
2. `df2 = df2.loc[diff_indices]`

What would be the difference between 1. and 2. above? What is the difference between `df.reindex` and `df.loc`?

Comment: perhaps `reindex` creates a new dataframe, `ix` returns a view

Comment: @PaulH that is not correct, NEITHER return views in general.

Comment: @Jeff you are, of course, absolutely right. what do `loc` and `iloc` do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both approaches return a new series/dataframe, and basically do the same thing.

The reason for the seeming redundancy is that, while using `loc` is syntacticly limiting (you can only pass a single argument to `__getitem__`), `reindex` is a method, which supports taking various optional parameters. ([docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html))

Comment: This is true for ``getting``, but you cannot set with ``reindex``

Comment: @jeff correct. I believe OP is asking about getting.

Comment: Thanks - What happens if I I want to update `df2` with the output of these commands? I am getting different results when using `reindex` with `inplace=True` vs using `ix` (I updated the OP)

Comment: @user815423426 it would help if you explained *what* different results you're getting

Comment: Thanks I will try to put together an example, but the first command one does **not** seem to change the Dataframe, while the second one does.